# How do you write "in" in logical form?

Tags: semantics, formal-semantics

> "There is a beer in the fridge."

*There exists a beer and there exists a fridge such that the beer is in the fridge.*

```
\exists x [BEER(x)] \exists y [FRIDGE(y)] IN(x,y)
```

I guess I never thought about simple cases like these but it seems like "in" is basically a predicate. I feel like I've mostly heard locations described as adverbial clauses. I suppose they are, but I hadn't thought about how some clauses can be either predicate or non-predicate clauses.

"The book is red" and "The red book" are different grammatically - one is a clause, the other is not. Maybe that difference can be reflected in the system above like:

```
\exists x [BOOK(x)] RED(x)

\exists x [BOOK(x) & RED(x)]
```

Maybe it's simple after all. In this logical system, you declare "referents" (x, y, etc.), assign them attributes if necessary, and must always follow with a "predicate" (which is actually conceptually unrestricted, could be an adjective, verb, or some other kind of information). It's like the referents have to get assigned to at least one function, they can't be declared but not used. Not sure if that's a principle or not.

This confuses me about adverbs though -

> The dog barks loudly.

*There exists a dog such that the dog barks and the dog barks loudly.*

I think you would run into limitations to think that adverbs are just adjective/predicates on the noun ("and the dog is loud"), but I guess that could at least be the formality of this system:

```
\exists x [DOG(x)] BARK(x) & LOUD(x)
```

I think you would inevitably find situations where it is unmistakable that the adverb is qualifying the verb itself, not the noun. But the way this system works, a verb cannot be an entity that another function can take. Verbs *are* the functions.

The only resolutions I can think of would be making verbs functions after all, like:

*There exists a dog and there exists an action such that if the action is barking, the barking is loud.*

Or you can subscript the verbs with adverbs, but I would worry it's not extensible to other adverbs, plus it's not clear what it is implying conceptually. Perhaps it is a logic where anything predicative is part of the formula, anything "attributive" is a subscript?

Comment: When you use "IN" as a relationship between two things, you're actually asserting not just the relationship, but attributes of the objects. To say that "X is in Y", you are saying that (1) Y is a container, and (2) X can be contained: `∃x,y: CONTAINER(y) & CONTAINABLE(x) & CONTAINS(y,x)`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Couldn't you just call the first two presuppositions of the third?

Comment: Well, no, not in formal logic you're not. You may be presupposing it or entailing it, but formal logic doesn't deal with physical objects or properties. It deals only with abstract, formally defined entities. If you want to make `IN` a formal logical entitiy, all you have to do is use it: _IN (X, Box)_ means "X is in a box". Everything else is provided by pragmatics. See [Framenet]{https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/} for details.